# dompdf page-break-inside: avoid on table not working

Tags: css, dompdf

I want to keep both the `th` and `td` tags in th same page. I have multiple table with only one `th` and one `td` tag and I used `page-break-inside: avoid` on the `table` but I get this result: [pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfPb7.png)
I would like to have the title and the content in the same page. How can I do ?

EDIT: This is my html:

```
<div id="compilazione_ordini">
   <table>
      <tr><th>Ord5</th></tr>
      <tr><td><textarea name='ordini[5][testo]'></textarea></td></tr>
   </table>       
   <table>
      <tr><th>Ord6</th></tr>
      <tr><td><textarea name='ordini[6][testo]'></textarea></td></tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
#compilazione_ordini table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#compilazione_ordini th{
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;
}
#compilazione_ordini textarea{
    border:none;
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height: 16em;
    padding:2px;
    resize:vertical;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: block;
}
#compilazione_ordini td{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to include the code that produces this image. See [MCVE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dompdf (up to and including 0.7.1) does not support page-break styling on table elements ([issue 1223](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1223)). Until that is resolved, for such a small table, you should be able to add the page-break styling to a container div.

```css
.nobreak {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
#compilazione_ordini table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#compilazione_ordini th{
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;
}
#compilazione_ordini textarea{
    border:none;
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height: 16em;
    padding:2px;
    resize:vertical;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: block;
}
#compilazione_ordini td{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="compilazione_ordini">
  <div class="nobreak">
    <table>
      <tr><th>Ord5</th></tr>
      <tr><td><textarea name='ordini[5][testo]'></textarea></td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="nobreak">
    <table>
      <tr><th>Ord6</th></tr>
      <tr><td><textarea name='ordini[6][testo]'></textarea></td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Following up for a different use case...one not directly related to your question but to table headers in general. Let's say you have a table with lots of rows that does need to page and display the header above the content rows on each page. You can do this by placing it in a THEAD element.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Ord5</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><textarea name='ordini[5][testo]'></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td><textarea name='ordini[5][testo]'></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td><textarea name='ordini[5][testo]'></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td><textarea name='ordini[5][testo]'></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td><textarea name='ordini[5][testo]'></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td><textarea name='ordini[5][testo]'></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td><textarea name='ordini[5][testo]'></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td><textarea name='ordini[5][testo]'></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td><textarea name='ordini[5][testo]'></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td><textarea name='ordini[5][testo]'></textarea></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```